# Firebird group by

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird, firebird2.5

Let's say I have an table with this data:

```
prename    name      date  
--------------------------
prename1   name1     date1
prename2   name2     date1
prename3   name3     date2
```

How do I get the right group by query so it will look like:

```
date    name         prename
-------------------------
date1   name1,name2  prename1,prename2
...       ...          ...
```

I need to get my name and prename from another table so i work with outer joins:

```
select u.name, u.prename, extract(day from date) as day
from t1 u
    full join t2 d on d.id = u.id
group by day
```

I get the error:

> Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26635575/330315

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would seem to want a query such as:

```
select extract(day from date) as dte, list(u.name, ',') as names,
       list(u.prename, ',') as prenames
from t1 u join
     t2 d
     on d.id = u.id
group by extract(day from date)
order by dte;
```

Notes:
 - It is highly unlikely that you need `full outer join`.  Start with an `inner join` and see if that does what you want.
 - The expressions in the `group by` define each row in the result set.
 - `list()` does the aggregate string concatenation.