# How to get resulted query from below SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join 3 SQL Server tables to show respective result but I am not able to get which join I want to use for it.

SQL Server tables are like this:

Table A

```
   | Col A-1  |  Col A-2 | Parent ID |
   +----------+----------+-----------+
   | 1        |  Test-1  |    1      |
   | 2        |  Test-2  |    1      |
   | 3        |  Test-3  |    1      |
   | 4        |  Test-4  |    1      |
   | 5        |  Test-5  |    2      |
```

Table B

```
   | Col B-1  |  Col B-2    |  Col B-3 | Col B-4(Foreign Key-Col A-1)|
   +----------+-------------+----------+------------------------+
   | 1        |  Profile-1  |  AutoSet |    4                   |       
   | 2        |  Profile-2  |  Circuit |    3                   |
```

Table C

```
  |Col C-1 |   Col C-2    |  Col C-3  |   Col C-4    |  Parent ID |
  +--------+--------------+-----------+--------------+------------+
  |1       |   Profile-1  |  AutoSet  |   AutoSet-1  |   1        |
  |2       |   Profile-1  |  Autoset  |   AitoSet-2  |   1        | 
  |3       |   Profile-2  |  Circuit  |   Circuit-1  |   1        |
```

Result I want to show like this (when values available in table B then not to concat in result table):

```
| Col C-2    |  Col C-3  |  Col C-4   |  Col A-2 (Concated)   | Parent ID |
+------------+-----------+------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| Profile-1  |  AutoSet  |  AutoSet-1 |  Test-1,Test-2,Test-3 |    1      |
| Profile-1  |  AutoSet  |  AutoSet-2 |  Test-1,Test-2,Test-3 |    1      |
| Profile-2  |  Circuit  |  Circuit-1 |  Test-1,Test-2,Test-4 |    1      |
```

Comment: SQL Server. Updated my question

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15633373/string-equivalent-of-sum-to-concatenate

Comment: How is table C related to table B?

Comment: Col B-2 = Col C-2 AND Col B-3 = Col C-3

Comment: Can you edit your question to include table schema as SQL code? It makes relationships much clearer than trying to guess them from data.

Comment: @bhushbo Look you need to provide at least some kind of feedback if you want help. Have you found anything usefull in link i posted above? Does the answer helped you somehow and if not why?

Answer (score 2):

keep in mind that string_agg function is available from SQL Server 2017
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
If you don't want everything from Table C and need just intersection ( whats common between tables ) use inner join instead of left.

```
select    c.colc2,
          c.colc3,
          c.colc4,
          string_agg(a.cola2, ',') as cola2,
          c.parentID
from      tablec c 
left join tableb b on c.colc2 = b.colb2 and c.colc3 = b.colb3
left join tablea a on b.colb4 = a.cola1
group by  colc2, colc3, colc4, c.parentID
```